# upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04.1

Tags: system-installation

After upgrading (12.08.2014) from version `12.04` to `14.04.1`

I get an notification:
System program problem detected. Do you want to report the problem now?
So, after I click  "report problem" I get an empty desktop. 
The only thing I can is to use command-line interface by `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. 
What should I do to get Unity work correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try starting the gui first by using the command `sudo startx`.